# How to retrieve object from db by current field

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I use Hibernate 4 and have entity **Item**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = Product.class)
private Product product;

@Column
private int count

// Getters and setters here
}
```

In my DAO implementation I want to get object from db by referenced field **product** and update it. I try this:

```
public void addItem(Item item) {

    int productId = item.getProduct().getId();

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Item temp = (Item) session.get(Item.class, productId);

    temp.setCount(100);

    session.saveOrUpdate(temp);
}
```

This code find object by **id**, but I need by **productId**.

How to add criteria to this code?

Comment: First tell us what does not work and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: The id in Product is "id".

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Item.class)
   .setFetchMode("Product", FetchMode.JOIN)
   .add(Restrictions.eq("product.id", productId));
Item temp = (Item) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Or by using alias:

```
Item temp = (Item) session.createCriteria(Item.class)
                      .createAlias("product", "p")
                      .add(Restrictions.eq("p.id", productId))
                      .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: There are java.lang.NullPointerException when object is not exist in db. How to validate exception?

Comment: Where do you get a NPE?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is NPE.

Comment: Please post the code and tell us what line the NullPointerException is occuring on.

Comment: I just forget validate temp. I do **if (temp == null) { temp = item}**. It works! Thank you very much.